# Jquery json com indice

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, json

Preciso criar um resultado Json, onde o estado seja o índice.

```
<?php 
//header('Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8'); 

require_once('Connections/conexao.php');

$selec = "SELECT estado, kg, valorCap, valorExcedCap, valorAloremCap, prazoCap FROM transportadoras_valores WHERE id_transportadora = '".$_GET["id_transportadora"]."' "; 
$exec = mysql_query($selec, $conexao) or die(mysql_error()); 

while($campos=mysql_fetch_array($exec)) { 
    extract($campos); 
    $Array = Array(); 

    $Array[] = Array(
                        "estadoT"           => "$estado",
                        "valorCap"          => "$valorCap",
                        "valorExcedCap"     => "$valorExcedCap",
                        "valorAloremCap"    => "$valorAloremCap",
                        "prazoCap"          => "$prazoCap",
                    ); 

    $json_encode = json_encode($Array); 
    echo "<pre>";
    print_r($json_encode); 
    echo "</pre>";
} 
?>
```

RESULTADO DO CÓDIGO ACIMA:

> [{"estadoT":"AL","kg":"3"}]
>
> [{"estadoT":"AL","kg":"5"}]
>
> [{"estadoT":"AL","kg":"10"}]
>
> [{"estadoT":"AM","kg":"3"}]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tente assim

```
$Array[$estado] = array(
                        "estadoT"           => "$estado",
                        "valorCap"          => "$valorCap",
                        "valorExcedCap"     => "$valorExcedCap",
                        "valorAloremCap"    => "$valorAloremCap",
                        "prazoCap"          => "$prazoCap",
                    );
```